# Hiding base class property using new keyword in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a Scneario like this in my Server DLL class library.

```
 [DataContract]
public class Base
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Info { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Child : Base
{
    [DataMember]
    public new int Info { get; set; }


    public int Save()
    { 

    }
}
```

My WCF Proxy at client side creates a Reference class. It Renames "Info" to "Info1". And shows proper properties in Base class.My code compiles great. So far so good. When I try to run ChildProxy.Save() from my client it gives me error Saying

"There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:info. The InnerException message was 'Type 'ClientServiceLayer.InfoService.Info' with data contract name 'ArrayOfInfo:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Info_DLL' is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
"

How to hide the property of base class in WCF?

UPDATE:

Here is the call on the client-side

```
InvoiceServiceClient infoProxy = new InfoServiceClient(); 
invId = invfoProxy.Save();
```

Comment: Yes We have a service Class on top of this class which call Save method..so intentionally didn't kept it...Here's the Code at client 'InvoiceServiceClient infoProxy = new InfoServiceClient();
invId = invfoProxy.Save();'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/wcf/thread/97575d79-2b6c-4cc6-8c8e-450aff5008ea):

You can't. Although the Child class is "hiding" the Info property of its base class, the attribute is being read by the serializer.

You could try adding [DataMember(Name = "Info")] to the child class and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks..I tried this put [DataMember(Name = "Info")] in base and  [DataMember(Name = "Info2")] in child class. Now I am able to call Proxy.Save()...not giving me any error now. server also following oop methadology. but still I am getting two object "Info" & "Info1" at client side. Can we do something to that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use *KnownType Attribute* in your *DataContract*

[MSDN Data Contract Known Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx)

Comment: Yes we had tried that. Give us the same error. But now we have kept the [DataMember(Name = "Info")] & also KnownType both on the hiding property..But still it shows both "Info" & "Info1" with my object..Nvertheless we got to live with what MS is provinding.. Thanks..